# Upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4 shows a blank site

Tags: php

I am on a local server using ampps and I can change php version from 5.3 to 5.4 but when on 5.4 than my
website just goes blank. Error reporting is turned on to error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT), but still don't get any errors in order to fix any problems with 5.4

What can I do to debug and get all errors to show?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
All errors are turned on in the corresponding php.ini file but still just blank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: Check your apache error logs

Answer (score 0):

Enable all error message with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` when you change the PHP-Version you have a new *php.ini* file. Go in that file and enable the option *display_errors* then you get all errors and informations.

Otherwise set that option in your application `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Answer (score 0):

**Responding to my own question**

I located the error by using the code provided in this post as suggested by [Mike B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46675/mike-b):

[PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

In one of my session variables I had suppressed errors with '@' `@$_SESSION['sessionname'];` which
made the error not to show and for that reason white screen of death.

Fixed! Thanks for the help.